# Remove axis from Parallel Coordinates in d3.js using Library https://github.com/syntagmatic/parallel-coordinates#parallel-coordinates

Tags: javascript, d3.js, parallel-coordinates

I want to remove the axis from the Parallel coordinate on dragend. Here is my code snippnet. 
It works partially as dimensions get removed but the lines corresponding to the dimensions still remain there. 
I need to update the xscale.domain. But somehow it doesn't work

```
  if (dragging[d] < 12 || dragging[d] > w() - 12) 
      {
        pc.remove_axis(d, g);
      }


   pc.remove_axis = function (d, g) {
   g_data = pc.getOrderedDimensionKeys();
   g_data = _.difference(g_data, [d]);
    xscale.domain(g_data);
    g.attr("transform", function (p) {
        return "translate(" + position(p) + ")";
    });
    g.filter(function (p) {
        return p === d;
    }).remove();}
```